# ./configure won't work while trying to install GNU tar 1.28

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to install GNU tar-1.28 and when I type `./configure` I get:

```
./configure: line 3064: config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 3074: config.log: Permission denied
line 3064: | #define HAVE_DECL_FWRITE_UNLOCKED 1
line 3074: | #define HAVE_GETCWD 1
```

Can anyone help me fix these errors?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to compile `tar` ? Is is included in Ubuntu by default.

Comment: It looks like permission/ownership. Can the userid running `./configure` write `$PWD`?